# Doctrine createQueryBuilder - How get data from foreign key

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have two database tables which were created with make:entity

- participant (id, firstname, lastname, age, gender, school*, group*, ...)
- school (id, name)

Participant has a field "school" which stores an id that is also a foreign key which points to an entry in school table.

In my frontend I want to show just a subset of the fields of the participant table.
An easy solution would be to skip the irrelevant fields, but the participant_table.twig template is used multiple times in my application.
There should be different views which show more or less participant data depending who's using the view.
This approach would lead to too much logic in the template in order control what's going to be shown/hidden.

So I need to build a custom query in the ParticipantRepository.php class which passes the data to the template.

Example:
$query = "participant.Firstname, participant.Lastname, participant.Age, participant.Gender ..."

And now the tricky part: how do I fetch the school's name by it's foreign key?

In the end I want to have an array with the following structure:

```
[
  0 => [     
    "Firstname" => "Jon"     
    "Lastname" => "Doe"     
    "Age" => 6     
    "Gender" => "m"     
    "School" => "School X"   
  ]   
  1 => [
    "Firstname" => "Mike"     
    "Lastname" => "Doe"     
    "Age" => 10     
    "Gender" => "m"     
    "School" => "School Y"   
  ]   
  ... 
]
```

Searched in Symfony, Docrtine docs, Stackoverflow..

Comment: If you have the `Participant` entity in the template does `{{ participant.school.name }}` not work?

Comment: I didn't follow the template portion of your question but if all you want is an array of arrays then drop down to sql and query for exactly what you need for a given view.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a join in your custom query in the ParticipantRepository.php class. The join will allow you to fetch the school name from the school table based on the foreign key in the participant table. Here's an example:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
->select('p.Firstname', 'p.Lastname', 'p.Age', 'p.Gender', 's.name as School')
->join('p.school', 's')
->getQuery();

$result = $query->getArrayResult();
```

Comment: I was already thinking about using joins but couldn't figure it out the right way. Thanks for your example. It got me on track.